# Sequelize - Many-to-Many - Get all relations for an object that has at least one relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models : Brand and Category, and they are linked with a Many to Many relation. Categories are optional for brands.

I'd like to create a "Category" filter, and for that, I would need to get all the Brands that have the category which is filtered, but still need to get all the categories linked to the brand.

Here is what I have :

```
Brand.findAll({
    attributes: ['id'],
    include: [
        {
            model: Category,
            as: 'categories',
            attributes: ['id'],
            where: {},
            through: {where:{id:1}},
        },
    ],
    order : [['name','ASC']],
    offset: offset,
    limit: limit,
})
```

And here is the MySQL it generates :

```
SELECT brand.id,
FROM (
    SELECT brand.id  
    FROM brands AS brand 
    WHERE ( 
        SELECT brandCategory.brandId 
            FROM brandCategories AS brandCategory 
            INNER JOIN categories AS category ON brandCategory.categoryId = category.id 
            WHERE (
                brand.id = brandCategory.brandId AND brandCategory.id = 1
            ) LIMIT 1 
    ) IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY brand.name ASC 
    LIMIT 0, 20
)
AS brand 
INNER JOIN (
    brandCategories AS categories.brandCategory 
    INNER JOIN categories AS categories ON categories.id = categories.brandCategory.categoryId AND categories.brandCategory.id = 1
) ON brand.id = categories.brandCategory.brandId
```

The where object of the include makes it required, so I have the request that checks that a Category exists. But as it is also in the INNER JOIN at the end, it doesn't get all categories, but only the one filtered.

If I use the `where : {id : 1}` directly in the include and not in "through", I don't get all linked models + pagination doesn't work, as the LIMIT is within the request that only checks that a relation exists (but not linked to the filtered ID).

Should I forget the where and through parameters in the include, and use a literal expression in a where directly at the root of findAll, to replace the function that checks that a relation exists ?

Comment: Where in the documentation do you see through as a key for the object passed into the findAll method? I am looking here at this page (http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database). It says this about joining many to many:  "In the case of many-to-many joins, you are also able to sort by attributes in the through-table". The code sample it gives is `Company.findAll({
  include: [ { model: Division, include: [ Department ] } ],
  order: [ [ Division, DepartmentDivision, 'name' ] ]
});`

Comment: Found this here : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll : below, you have : options.include[].through.where. But I don't think ordering is going to solve my issue